# How to implement tiered storage in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, archive, nosql

I am trying to get information on implementation of tiered storage on HBase which runs over HDFS. I have read about the tiered storage on HDFS from this [link](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2015/01/12/hdfs-storage-efficiency-using-tiered-storage/). I have also gone through this [link](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hdfs_hsm_and_hbase_part) but I still have doubts related to implementation.

1. On HDFS, based on the access frequency I can move files from one storage type to another storage type. But as HBase stores files on HDFS, how would I know the access frequency of files and If I move file on HDFS directly, would the mapping between HBase and HDFS will get disturbed because of this movement ?
2. For moving data on HDFS, do I need to write my own logic or is it possible to have a configuration, and some HBase utility will move the data from one storage to another for me ?

I understand the concept of tiered storage, I have doubts related to the implementation.

If you can share any information on same or give me link to blog/article, that will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you are tying to implement is called [Lambda Architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/). Besides provided link, I recommend you to search the internet, there are plenty of examples about the decisions people make when implementing such system.